# Client-side validation for custom editor templates in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates

I have a viewModel that contains an object.  I've defined a custom editor template for that object, which allows me to edit each of the children of that object.  The children values aren't required serverside (so I don't have any Required annotations), however if the user reaches this particular input, it should be required.

Is there any way I can inspect the values of these children objects (within the viewModel) in the POST method, and return some errors to the view if they are null?

I'm using Razor.

Comment: Are you using pure razor syntax or Knockout or HTML or ... ?

Comment: Razor - just updated my question to include this

Comment: In the title you mention "Client-side Validation", but you say in your question "in the POST method, and return some errors to the view ...", which is usually on the server-side. Which do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to write a function that will be check user input (on change in that field)

> if the user reaches this particular input

and if user reaches that particular input you use jQuery to add `@class = "required"` HTML attribute to your object. From that moment on it will become `required`

Take a look [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression): this is jQuery validator for required field based on some condition. I think this is exactly what you're after

**Edit**

Your other option is to use AJAX to go back to server to verify what you're looking for. Example is [here](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/11/ajax-calls-to-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-using-jquery/)

Hope this makes sense and is of help to you.

Comment: Thank you very much.  What alternatives do I have if the element already has a class defined, that I can't change?

Comment: Also - I'm interested in checking the viewModel serverside as well just in case they POST without javascript.  Do you know how I can do this y passing the model back to the view, while giving the view awareness of the validation errors?

Comment: Absolutely. You use AJAX to do that. Look here for example http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/11/ajax-calls-to-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-using-jquery/. You right, you can do either on the client as I suggested on call to server using AJAX - this is another option. To your first question - you can change any class with jQuery, you find that element with $ and set its class to whatever you want, requited in this case.

Answer (score 1):

On the server-side, you could check the child objects of the class in your action,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyClass myClass)
{
    if (myClass.Children.Any(child => child == null))
    {
        foreach(var child in myClass.Children
            .Where(child => child == null)
            .Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index))
        {

             ModelState.AddModelError(
                 string.Format("Children[{0}]", child.Index), 
                 "Must be required");
        }

        return this.View("...");
    }
}
```